# How to show UWP splash screen without title?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

Microsoft Store is the title and that does not appear during the splash screen. But in our app, the splash screen contains the title. How to make it go away on the splash screen? We are using Xamarin.Forms UWP project.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above screenshot is set `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` as true to hide the title, you could call the following method in the UWP client app's `OnLaunched` method to hidden the title, and it will effect when next start. For more detail please refer to [Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/title-bar)

```
private void extendAcrylicIntoTitleBar()
{
    CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
    ApplicationViewTitleBar titleBar =
    ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
}


 protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
 {
     extendAcrylicIntoTitleBar();
     .............
 }
```

Comment: This works for Splash. But once the page is loaded, I want the title to come. The current code hides the titlebar completely.

Comment: Ok, currently you could refer above document to make custom title bar and place textblock here to display app's title